xml config file not found
A question on paths
I have made an executable in VB.net, the file needs a specific xml with parameters or else it will not run
Public XML_file as string = "xxx.xml"

the file is xxx.xml and sits in the same folder as the executable, when I run the exe from the folder there is no issue and the xml is found
how ever when I call the exe from within another program or command line, the xml is not found
I cannot hardcode the xml path cause the exe is used on different workstations
any idea please
tried copying both files to several directories

When you specify the name of a file without specifying the folder path, it is assumed to be in the current directory for the process.
When you run your own EXE directly, unless you specify otherwise, the current directory for the process will be the folder containing the EXE. If you look at a Windows desktop shortcut for an app, you'll see that there is a Working Directory field. That is one way you can set the current directory for the process when you run an app from a shortcut.
When you run an EXE from code, the working directory for the new process will be inherited from your process, so it will not be the folder containing the second EXE unless it is in the same folder as the first EXE.
So, what's happening is that you are trying to open a file in the current directory but, when your app is run from another app, the current directory does not contain that file, so it fails.
There are multiple possible solutions. The best option is to NEVER use just a file name and ALWAYS use the full path. How you would do that depends on the situation and type of app. In your case, you should get the path of the folder containing your EXE and qualify the file name with that. If yours is a Windows Forms app, you might do that like so:
Public XML_file as string = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "xxx.xml")

If it's a different type of app then you may need to get the folder path a different way. In that case, update your question and add a comment to this answer to let me know that I need to update the answer.

I think you could always use System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly and the Location property regardless of the type of app.
